# CSS Stop all elements on a page from shrinking

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to stop all elements - Div's, tables, images etc from shrinking. So that when the browser is made smaller user will have to scroll around to see page?

example: http://uk.godaddy.com/

On my wrapper class I've tried various things such a:

```
width: 100%;
min-width:100px;
width: auto
```

position relative;

I works on first resize of browser but after a coupld of second's it all shrinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At your wrapper, set fixed width in pixels, like

```
.container {
   width: 1200px;
   margin:auto;
}
```

Moreover, the `margin:auto;` will make your container horizontally centered.

The reason it may shrink could be the `width:100%;` or `width:auto;`. When your browser width will reach the container's width, then, the container's width will be adjusted to the browser making the page smaller (to fit the screen).

If you want to achieve something better than GoDaddy, you should definitely read about responsive web design and media queries. Maybe you can tweak your layout in that way, that it will appear on smaller screens better (without any horizontal scrollbar).

Comment: HI Thanks I added the width in 'px' with margin: auto and it's stopped stuff shrinking. I was wondering though how this affects other areas, such as when user views the site on larger or smaller screens

Comment: As you have margin:auto; the users with bigger screens will see your page centered. You can try it by resizing your browser (CTRL + "-"). It should give you an overview. On smaller screens - as you wanted, the page will be horizontally scrollable. But as long as your page is not mobile-ready, you don't have to worry about that. See W3 http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp for statistics about resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

On you wrapper/container class do this

```
.wrapper{
     width:1200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Keep in mind to make all measurements in "px". Give width,heights etc in ".px" and you will be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Give your wrapper a fixed width such as

```
width: 1000px;
```

The reason min-width: 100px probably isn't working for you is because it will allow elements inside to shrink *until* the browser window is 100px or smaller. Width 100% is sort of opposite from making the user scroll around because no matter how small you make the window, your container will be forced to be 100% of that width.